# How to assert that a button is disabled in React Native Testing Library?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

How can I assert that a button is disabled in React Native Testing Library? I would imagine something like:

```js
expect(getByRole('button')).toBeDisabled()
```

but RNTL doesn't provide `toBeDisabled` assertion.

Comment: `.toHaveAttribute('disabled')`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The correct method is `toHaveProp`.

Comment: At the end I've found out that there is `.toBeDisabled` indeed. Doc: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-native#tobedisabled

Answer (score 3):

this is a common issue due to RN nature. I have managed to reach my goal by just testing the actual effect of callback function, not just comparing the number of calls or something like that...

```js
describe('<Button /> - ', () => {
  let state = false
  const onPressMock = jest.fn(() => {
    state = !state
  })
  const props: ButtonProps = {
    text: 'Submit',
    onPress: onPressMock
  }

  it('should become disabled', () => {
    // act: render container
    const { container } = render(<Button {...props} isDisabled />)

    // assert 1: check if button receives {isDisabled}
    expect(container.props.isDisabled).toEqual(true)
    
    // act2: fire callback
    fireEvent(container, 'onPress')
    
    // assert 2: "state" should remain as false.
    expect(state).toEqual(false)
  })
})
```

make sure that your button looks like:

```js
const isBlockedInteraction: boolean = isLoading || isDisabled;

return (
  <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={!isBlockedInteraction && onPress}
    disabled={isBlockedInteraction}
    {...props}
  />
)
```

Comment: this solution for some reason doesn't work in react native... it still says that the function was called once and still changes the variable `state` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Quite a simple try `toHaveProperty` method, I hope that helped.

example:

```js
import React from 'react'
import {fireEvent, render} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import {SignInScreen} from './SignInScreen';

it('disabled button if email and password are empty', () => {
  const screen = render(<SignInScreen />);
  const button = screen.getByText('Login');

  // screen.debug();
  // console.log(button.props);

  expect(button.props).toHaveProperty('disabled', true);
});
```